# In 2-by-2 partitions of two rectangles, is there always a pair of non-overlapping parts?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

There are two rectangles, red and blue.
Each rectangle is partitioned into 4 sub-rectangles using one cut parallel to its longer side and two cuts parallel to its shorter side, like this:

[image]

Does there always exits a pair of sub-rectangles, one red and one blue, that do not overlap?

NOTE: Initially I thought that the answer should be positive even when partitioning to 3 sub-rectangles. However, I found a negative example. In the partitions below, each blue sub-rectangle overlaps all three red sub-rectangles (and vice versa):

[image]

EDIT: here is a [Geogebra worksheet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/gkbtbnzv) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes, there always exists a pair of sub-rectangles that do not overlap. Here is an outline proof.

Let the segment of the long cut that lies between the two points of intersection with the shorter cuts be called the Central Segment (CS).

Suppose that all four blue sub-rectangles overlap all four red sub-rectangles.

Then consider one blue sub-rectangle R. Each of the four red sub-rectangles must contain a point that is within R. Take four such points, one from each red sub-rectangle, and join them to make a quadrilateral Q.

Each edge of Q must lie within R (since it connects two points in R). Therefore Q lies fully within R.

Now Q must either intersect with the CS of the red rectangle, or it must fully enclose it (since the only way to draw such a quadrilateral without intersecting the red CS is to encircle it). Therefore the red CS passes through R.

The same is true for each blue sub-rectangle. Therefore the red CS passes through each blue sub-rectangle.

Let K and M be the two ends of the red CS, as shown in this diagram:

[image: Red CS passes through each blue sub-rectangle]

Note any segment that passes through each blue sub-rectangle - as the red CS does here - must cross both the blue CS and the two shorter cuts of the blue rectangle. (Such a segment may or may not continue beyond the bounds of the blue rectangle.)

Now consider the red sub-rectangle with a vertex at M whose edges do not overlap the red CS. There are two possible positions of this sub-rectangle, shown by the two dashed rectangles MOPL and MNQL in the diagram. But neither of these can possibly overlap with the blue rectangle that either contains or is nearest to K (the other end of the red CS), shown as GDFH in the diagram. This can be proved by (for example) considering the projection of the rectangle GDFH onto the line KL: this projection is entirely within the segment KM, while the projections of the potential red sub-rectangles MOPL and MNQL are the segment ML.

Therefore we have a red sub-rectangle that doesn't overlap with a blue sub-rectangle, and have reached a contradiction.

Comment: The sentence I am unsure of is "Now Q must either intersect with the CS of the red rectangle, or it must fully enclose it".  Consider the example with 3 rectangles at the bottom of the question. A red rectangle can overlap all three blue rectangles, without touching the blue central point. A blue rectangle can overlap all three red rectangles, without touching the red central point. Why is it different with 4?

Comment: "Let A and B be the two end-points of the red CS. Now consider the red sub-rectangle with a vertex at A whose edges do not overlap the red CS. This rectangle cannot intersect the blue sub-rectangle that contains B," --- this sentence, in isolation, is not true at the top figure in the question: the top-right red rectangle overlaps the rightmost blue rectangle. 
NOTE: I uploaded a Geogebra worksheet: https://www.geogebra.org/m/gkbtbnzv so that you can play with it online.

Comment: Here is an idea to make the first claim (about intersection with CS) more formal. Let's rotate and scale the coordinate system such that the long cut of the red rectangle is at $x=0$, and the two short cuts are at $y=-1$ and $y=1$. 
Consider a blue sub-rectanble B that intersects all four red sub-rectangles. Then B must have a point with $x<0,y<-1$ and $x<0,y>-1$, so it must have a point with $x<0,y=-1$. Similarly it must have a point at $x>0,y=1$. Therefore, by convexity it must have a point at $x=0, y\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: [continued] The blue CS must pass through all red subrectangles, so its projection on the y axis must strictly contain the red CS. By similar considerations, the projection of the red CS on the long blue cut must strictly contain the blue CS. But this is a contradiction, since one projection must be longer than the other.

Comment: That sounds promising... With regard to the later claim (about the red sub-rectangle at A not being able to intersect the blue one that contains B), it's true that in isolation it's false; I meant it in the context of the previous statement, i.e. that the red CS crosses both the blue CS and the two shorter cuts of the blue rectangle. A diagram will make it clearer what I mean - I will have a go with GeoGebra, thanks.

Comment: I have edited my answer to improve the last part with the help of a diagram. Your more formal argument for the first part (why the red CS must pass through each blue sub-rectangle) seems correct to me. I wonder if the rest of the argument could be similarly formalised? P.s. I had an inkling that convexity was important, since it's not strictly true that you can't draw a quadrilateral whose vertices lie one in each sub-rectangle without either intersecting or enclosing the CS: a concave one will do it! Nevertheless, the rectangle containing such a concave quadrilateral will enclose the CS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By what name can I cite your answer?

Comment: My name is Jack Young, or you can use "alcana", I don't mind. I realised last part of the argument could be simplified somewhat: since KM passes through all 4 blue sub-rectangles, it passes through GDFH and EIJB. Therefore, if we rotate the axes so that the long cut of the blue rectangle is parallel to the y-axis, we can say KM must have a positive gradient. Therefore a perpendicular to KM has a negative gradient. Therefore the perpendicular at M, having a negative gradient, cannot pass through GDFH. Therefore GDFH does not overlap the red sub-rectangle on the other side of that perpendicular.